Given a list of objects, insert, update and delete them using Jdbc or JdbcTemplate in one SQL statement
I figured that the best way to do a merge operation is to use a common table expression.
The query below takes a list of two items and will create missing items, update matching and delete those that exist in the database but are missing from the list.
WITH updated AS (
    INSERT INTO items ("id", "body")
        VALUES (?, ?), (? ?)
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
            "body" = excluded."body"
            RETURNING id)
    DELETE FROM items WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM updated)

However, I am a bit puzzled how to construct the placeholders for the varying number of items.
So far, I do it with a simple
var placeholder = "(?, ?)";
List<String> placeholders = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <  items.size(); i++) {
  placeholders.add(placeholder);


and just substitute them in the sql so tha the full code looks as follows:
getJdbcTemplate().update("""
WITH updated AS (
    INSERT INTO items ("id", "body")
        VALUES %s
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
            "body" = excluded."body"
            RETURNING id)
    DELETE FROM items WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM updated)
        """.formatted(String.join(", ", placeholders)), new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                int i = 1; // position of the placeholder
                for (Item item : items) {
                    ps.setInt(i++, item.getId());
                    ps.setInt(i++, item.Body());
                }
            }
        });

Notice the %s inside the text block and the .formatted(String.join(", ", placeholders))
Is there a more sophisticated way of doing the same? Like a JDBC or JdbcTemplate primitive for constructing varying placeholder lists? Or probably a way to do the same with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ?
The DB used is Postgresql, but the syntax above is faily standard, AFAIU.
